# My horizontal navigation menu shows as 1 line in chrome, others shows 2 lines

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a navigation menu with this style. The menu is perfect on Chrome, but other browsers and some Firefox versions, the menu shows up as 2 lines. I cannot get this line of CSS "padding: 0 0.73em;" to work on all browsers.

```
.mainnav ul {
 list-style-type:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.mainnav ul li {
 float:left;
}
.mainnav ul li a:link,.mainnav ul li a:visited {
 display:block;
 font-size:13px;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 background-color:#B79527;
 text-align:center;
 padding:4px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 margin:0;
 padding: 0 0.73em;
 height: 28px;
 line-height: 28px;
 position:relative;
 white-space:nowrap;
}
.mainnav ul li a:hover,.mainnav ul li a:active {
 background-color:#9A7C1C;
}
#firstmenu {
 background:#7A4AAD;
 padding-left: 6px;
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="mainnav">
 <ul>
  <li id="firstmenu"><a href="default.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.html">Group News</a></li>
  <li><a href="about_us.html">About us</a></li>
  <li><a href="vision.html">Vision Message and Mission</a></li>
  <li><a href="group_activities.html">Group Activity</a></li>
  <li><a href="charmain.html">Chairman's Message</a></li>
  <li><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
  <li><a href="contacts.html">Contact us</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Even Firefox gives me different results on different machines.

Comment: Are you saying that when you remove the padding, it does work? Also, which version(s) of Firefox? And, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/wL6xY/)

Comment: How wide is the parent container?

Comment: this seems pretty consistent across browsers. What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: Hi Lister..no when I decrease the padding it works, but not in chrome. The current style works on chrom.
Parent container is 900px
The issue is with the menu navigation. Show as 1 line in chrome, 2 lines on other broswes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are aware that in: `.mainnav ul li a:link,.mainnav ul li a:visited` there are double padding decalarations?

1. `padding:4px;`
2. `padding: 0 0.73em;`

You can combine those:

```
padding: 4px 0.73em;
```

Seems that the issue with the navigation list is that there is too much spacing in between them in combination with the amount of items.
I there are too much items, the normal behavior is the wrapping, **you could** decrease spacing, font-size to fix this.

Comment: Thank you,, Looks like re-sizing the font fix the issue of 2 lines. But now I have white space at the end of the menu in Chrome. I set the same background color of li to ul....works perfect. But one little problem remains is the empty space at the end, I wanted the menu item to be justified

Comment: [1]Thats on firefox:http://i.stack.imgur.com/hRFaa.png
[2]Thats on chrome:http://i.stack.imgur.com/TqYFC.png
[3]Thats on chrome when reducing the size:http://i.stack.imgur.com/c3TyS.png
[4]Thats when I fill the ul background:http://i.stack.imgur.com/i18PE.png

Comment: Did you use a CSS reset? change the <li> to inline-block in the css instead of float, text-align center on the wrapper, now all the links would be aligned in the center, no space to the right.